# What purpose does the app.UseAuthorization() default serve?

Tags: c#, .net

When I create a new .net project, the startup.cs automatically gets the following code line:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Without `app.UseAuthentication()`, what purpose does the above line serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With app usе сommands are activated or added so-called middleware through which the http request passes before reaching its end point (controller method, page handler ...), these middleware can be global or decorate pieces of code in the form of attributes. In this case, user authorization activates the authorization for the application and its attributes. You can read more about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Yes but without authentication  what purpose does authorization serve?

Comment: It just adds the own middelwares. If you do not set up authentication, they do nothing, do not need them, also you can remove this line of code.

Comment: There must be some reason it's added by default

Comment: Sure for example purposes, also some middlewares must be plased in order after or befor other middlewares and the Authorization is the last bulit in, after wich are the custom middlewares executed